# $\alpha$ belong to which group

Tags: cubics

In the below question

[image]

How from the first step they have written that $\alpha$ belong to (-1,0)

Comment: Using intermediate value theorem, one form of it states if a continuous function changes sign in an interval then there is a root in that interval in this case (-1,0).

Comment: @AsharTafhim how do we know it changes sign

Comment: $f(0)=1$ and $f(-1)=b-c<0$ so the function changes sign in this interval.